# RFID USB reader terminal reading with Bash

Tags: bash, arduino, rfid

I bought [an RFID USB kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/243) and haven't been able to read the RFID IDs with the following Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ read -r rfid ] ; do

#URL=http://www.mainpage.us/rfid/status.php?number=$rfid

#curl --request POST $URL

echo $rfid
sleep 1

done < /dev/cu.usbserial-A600JNHR
```

The RFID should work fine as per the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you should be making a serial connection to the device. See minicom, cutecom, putty, or GNU screen. Also, the [] is not needed in your loop condition.

Comment: Jordanm may be onto something, have you tried not using the `[]`? It shouldn't work with them.

Comment: minicom worked, it did give me an output on putty but the code above was not doing it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a command. Since you want to use `read`, you should not try to use `[`.